# Apache sticky session tomcat clustering session expiry

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, load-balancing

I have an application where I am facing session expired (not found) problem when session switching happens. I did load balancing in apache with sticky session.

When I run java web based application, sessions are created on both the tomcats as below
primary tomcat(tomcatA) - 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatA
secondary tomcat(tomcatB) - 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatA

Browser cookie shows JSESSIONID as 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatA. And every requests goes to tomcatA. At some point due to load balancing request goes to tomcatB. And session id becomes 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatB(in browser its still 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatA, and I found 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatB in servlet). So session is not found.

So is this default behavior or something I am doing wrong?

Is it correct scenario that both the tomcats have same 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatA as sessionId?

Should not there be 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatB for tomcatB?

Comment: What do you mean by "*session switching*"? You are using sticky-sessions on the load-balancer, but are you also using clustered-sessions on the Tomcat nodes? Please explain what you mean by "*I found [sessionid].tomcatB in servlet*".

Comment: For one user, all requests were going to tomcatA (It should as sticky session always sends request to the same tomcat). Suddenly request sent to tomcatB where it didnt find session, and user got login screen. Yes I am using sticky session in clustered environment. When I debug application, I found 0B04C708749BC91A3A872B753F74E938.tomcatB as sessionid in servlet/java code.